# Append filename to column header when reading multiple csv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, import

I want to read multiple .csv files and append the datetime part of their filename to the column header. Each csv file contains data acquired at a specific datetime. Each filename has the following format:

> yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm-ss_someothertext

Each file contains only one column of data.

I successfully import multiple files as a list of dataframes as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'C:\Users\...' #path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)
```

I then concatenate the files into one dataframe such that each column contains the data from one of the files:

```
frame = pd.concat(li, axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

However, this is where I lose the filename information. The column headers are now just a series of numbers. My question is: how can I append the datetime portion of each filename to its respective column header in `frame`?

The closest I have got is being able to append the whole filename, not just the datetime part, in a roundabout way by transposing `frame`, adding the whole filename as a new column, transposing back, then setting the filename row as the header row...

```
import os
frame=pd.DataFrame.transpose(frame)
frame['filename'] = os.path.basename(filename)
frame=pd.DataFrame.transpose(frame)
frame.reset_index(drop=True)
frame.columns = frame.iloc[6628] #row 6628 is where the row with the filenames ends up after transposing
```

This seems terribly inefficient though and ends up with the whole filename as the header rather than just the datetime part.

Comment: Does each file only contain one column of data?

Comment: @MrFuppes Yes, just one column

Comment: Check this from the pd.concat() docs: `ignore_indexbool, default False
If True, do not use the index values along the concatenation axis. The resulting axis will be labeled 0, …, n - 1. This is useful if you are concatenating objects where the concatenation axis does not have meaningful indexing information. Note the index values on the other axes are still respected in the join.` I think you want to leave this argument as False, then the original headers will be retained.

Comment: Now, if the original headers need additional information, that can still be addressed, but my above comment should fix the headers being turned into an incremental index from 0 to n-1.

Comment: @LiamFiddler I'm afraid changing that argument to False ends up adding the original column header in each file to the header row in `frame`, whereas I am trying to get a part of the filename into the header row in `frame`.

Comment: Gotcha, just wanted to make sure I understood what was happening and what the requirement is. I'll post a full answer below.

Comment: @R_Dax is the filename always in the same format, or is the date in the filename at least in the same format?

Comment: @LiamFiddler the filename is always in the same format, including the "someothertext" part. The "someothertext" part is just the name of the measurement device, which gets added on to the filename after the date+time of the measurement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be my suggested approach, squeezing the DataFrame and using Regex:

```
import re
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

path = 'C:\Users\....'
files = glob.glob(f'{path}\*.csv')

li = []

for file in files:
     name = os.path.basename(file)  # get filename
     date = re.search(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', name).group(0)  # extract yyyy-mm-dd from filename
     # read file, squeeze to Series, rename to date
     li.append(pd.read_csv(file, index_col=None, header=0, squeeze=True).rename(date))  

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=1, ignore_index=False)
```